# Minimal closed embedding of singular projective curve into some projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, schemes, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a reduced projective scheme of pure dimension 1 over a field $k$.

> What is the minimal number $N$ such that there is a closed immersion $X \to \mathbb{P}_k^N$?

For smooth $X$ this should be $N=3$ and for singular curves, this should definitely depend on the singularities (because of the tangent space that have higher dimension).

Where do I find such a result? Any hints and references are welcome, thank you!

Comment: See (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14177/is-there-a-whitney-theorem-type-theorem-for-projective-schemes)

Comment: @ParthivBasun +1 Thank you for your reference!!